# JOIN works in SQL not in Drupal

Tags: mysql, sql, drupal, drupal-7

I'm trying to make a module for Drupal 7.x. At a certain point I want to use a sql query (JOIN). When I try the query in MYSQL it works. But when I want to try it in Drupal, the array is empty.

So I guess there is a difference between the sql query and the drupal query (mayby the implemantion is different).

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT * FROM friends 
INNER JOIN users 
ON friends.uid=users.uid
```

**Drupal implementation**

```
    function project_myfriends(){
    // Use database API to retrieve tasks
    $query = db_select('friends', 'f');

    $query->join('users', 'u', 'f.uid = u.uid'); // JOIN

    $query->fields('u', array('name'))  
          ->execute();
    return $query;
    }

   /**
    * Implements hook_block_view().
    */
    function project_block_view($delta = ''){
    switch ($delta) {
        case 'project':
            $block['subject'] = t('My Friends');
            // Use our custom function to retrieve data
            $result = project_myfriends();

            $items = array();

            var_dump($result);
            foreach($result as $friend){
                $items[] = array(
                    'data' => $friend->name,            
                );
            }
            // No tasks
                if (empty($items)) {
                    $block['content'] = t('No friends.');
                }
                else {
                    // Pass data trough theme function
                    $block['content'] = theme('item_list', array(
                        'items' => $items));
                }
            }
        return $block;
    }
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to fetch your result query:

```
$result = project_myfriends()->execute()->fetchAll();
var_dump($result);
```